# Changing font color

Tags: php, wordpress

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && strtolower($title) == 'your account' ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $current_user->display_name;
}
```

So my objective is to display the `$current_user` with a different font color. How do I add HTML code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add html code by concatenating it to the string like so:

```
return '<span style="color:red">' . $current_user->display_name . '</span>';
```

However it is even better to use a string formatter like [`sprintf`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), this will keep your code clean:

```
return sprintf('<span style="color:red">%s</span>', $current_user->display_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a inline styled  span  (or you can assign a proper class to the wrapping span) 
Forn inline style you could use

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && strtolower($title) == 'your account' ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    **return "<span style='color: #FF0000;'>" . $current_user->display_name . "</span>" ;**
}
```